# Refresh Guava LoadingCache everyday at a specific time

Tags: java, caching, loading, guava

I need that my cache be refreshed everyday at a specific time, in my case, at midnight. I have way to do this with Guava LoadingCache?
So far I only got the cache be renewed after a day, with the next code:

```
private final LoadingCache<String, Long> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
    .refreshAfterWrite(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
    .build(new CacheLoader<String, Long>() {
        public Long load(String key) {
            return getMyData("load", key);
        }
}
```

Comment: Use a scheduled job that calls invalidateAll() on your cache every day at midnight.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a code snipped that implements [JB Nizeth's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet) answer (Java 8):

```
long millisUntilMidnight = Duration
            .between(LocalDateTime.now(), LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.now().plusDays(1), LocalTime.MIDNIGHT))
            .toMillis();
Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()
            .scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> cache.invalidateAll(), millisUntilMidnight,
            TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```