# How to invalidate guava cache at scheduled time?

Tags: java, caching, guava

I have a requirement in which it is required to invalidate or cleanup a cache every day around the fixed time. I can schedule a daily job to invalidate the cache at the fixed time. However, I am not looking for that.

Is there any other simpler approach to invalidate the cache like some in-built methods or are there any other suggestions?

Comment: Take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37642678/refresh-guava-loadingcache-everyday-at-a-specific-time

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`expireAfterAccess`](https://guava.dev/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html#expireAfterAccess(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)).

It specifies that each entry should be automatically removed from the cache once a fixed duration has elapsed after the entry's creation

```
expireAfterAccess(long duration, TimeUnit unit)
```

If you want to invalidate at specified time, you can create a schedular thread that runs at specific time and calls `invalidateAll()`